# Multiple buttons to trigger single jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to use multiple images to open the same jQuery dialog box. I have noticed that this only works for the first image, is there any way to make the second one work as well without giving it a unique id? There will be 100+ of these images so I don't want to create a new function for each image

```
$(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false},{ buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ]});
            $("#IMG").on("click", function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog box">Test</div> 

<input type="image" id="IMG" src="img/image.gif">
<input type="image" id="IMG" src="img/image.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a class for each image, say "img". Then declare a handler like this:

```
$(".img").on("click", function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs have to be unqiue. Use a class instead:

```
$(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false},{ buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ]});
            $(".open-img").on("click", function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog box">Test</div> 

<input type="image" class="open-img" src="img/image.gif">
<input type="image" class="open-img" src="img/image.gif">
```